# Is there a way to change application audio to a different audio device?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, winapi, audio

I want to be able to change Audio Output/Input device per each application just like in Windows Settings Volume Mixer where you can click on a application and you can change `Output device` and `Input Device`.

I've tried using a Registry Editor and figured out It was in Registry location of `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Audio\DefaultEndpoint`
and each folder is 8bit + _0 (idk why) inside of each folder have `default` key. and I figured out if you change audio output/input device at the same dir you should see new `000_000`, `000_000_p`, `001_000`, and `001_000_p` and when you delete this key and restart you audio service It will change it to `default`.

My question is there a way to change it? I couldn't find Windows api doc for it. but I did see some other application is able to do it such as https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet and https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router

I do believe that those other keys are storing output/input device
[image]

Also I found this too https://github.com/Belphemur/SoundSwitch/blob/dev/SoundSwitch.Audio.Manager/AudioSwitcher.cs#L109

Comment: Hopping someone is able to help me to get it working in Python

Answer (score 0):

The sources you attached show [Windows.Media.Internal.AudioPolicyConfig](https://github.com/Belphemur/SoundSwitch/blob/d5380f894f118c3a4e13a04095d073e653aadaba/SoundSwitch.Audio.Manager/Interop/Client/Extended/AudioPolicyConfig.cs#L41) 's [SetPersistedDefaultAudioEndpoint](https://github.com/Belphemur/SoundSwitch/blob/d5380f894f118c3a4e13a04095d073e653aadaba/SoundSwitch.Audio.Manager/Interop/Client/Extended/AudioPolicyConfig.cs#L122) function Or [IPolicyConfigVista](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router/blob/19a4b299803221da462f047e9a120d5c77bff4ab/audio-router-gui/policy_config.cpp#L11) Interface 's globally *SetDefaultEndpoint*. And It seems **audio-router** changes the destination process through [swapping virtual table](https://github.com/audiorouterdev/audio-router/blob/19a4b299803221da462f047e9a120d5c77bff4ab/audio-router/patch_iaudioclient.cpp#L23) between the two Interface objects.

Comment: Isn't the IPolicyConfigVista you linked to only changes global audio device?

Comment: @Damien *IPolicyConfigVista*  changes audio device globally.

Comment: I am trying route audio process to another audio output device